# Angular2 + Nginx Deep Linking/Routing Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, angular, nginx

I deployed an Angular2 application on my Apache web server and with the following .htaccess,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

and an additional configuration in index.html,

```
<base href="/applicationName/">
```

the application was able to load without any issue and there was no redirection problem.

I'm now trying to setup the same application in my Nginx server but I couldn't seem to make it work.

I understand that there is no .htaccess in Nginx, how do I convert the above .htaccess to work in Nginx main configuration?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This problem has been since fully documented in the Angular documentation : [Routed apps must fallback to index.html](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback)

Answer (score 2):

Nginx is actually quite a lot easier than apache in my opinion. One way to do it is to create a server block like this. This is of course if you have access to the configuration file of nginx on your server.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    root   /path/to/your/index;
    index index.html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pierre, I have tried the above block in my default configuration file but still no luck.

Comment: I am able to load the main index page but when I try to perform a process, eg. login, I'm getting error 500,

==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
2016/10/24 01:45:59 [error] 1005#0: *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 123.123.123.123, server: example.com, request: "POST /identity/api/users/login.json HTTP/1.1", host: "123.123.123.123", referrer: "http://domain.com/application/login"

Comment: Ah, another thing to note is that there will be multiple applications running on the same server, so the root is set to /var/www/html as the main document root, and I would add the application name after / in the browser address bar.